# If you remove a submanifold of codimension 1 from its manifold do you get a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Suppose I have a manifold $\mathcal{M}$ and a closed submanifold $\mathcal{N} \subset \mathcal{M}$ of codimension 1. If I remove the closed submanifold $\mathcal{N}$ from $\mathcal{M}$  will I be left with a manifold?

I am not sure if it is true but it looks very plausible. However, I am pretty sure that if would only hold for codimension 1. For example in the manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$ I can take the submanifold complement to a figure "8".

Furthermore, would the statement also be true for smooth manifolds or symplectic manifolds?

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, for example remove $(0,1) \times \{0\}$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @ChrisEagle What about if you remove a closed submanifold?

Comment: Then the result is open, hence clearly a manifold.

Comment: But open subsets of manifolds are always manifolds, right? Just restrict the charts. Also, it's not obvious to me that the figure 8 is a manifold.

Comment: @DylanMoreland I am taking the submanifold to be the complement of the figure "8" so the two open disk inside the figure and the open punctured space surrounding it, this is a manifold.

Comment: @ChrisEagle So my statement would hold for closed submanifold?

Comment: @user29751: Yes, but for boring reasons: as Dylan says, an open subset of a manifold is always a manifold.

Comment: @user29751:  But it's not just that you can remove a closed *manifold*, you can even remove any closed set.  So, if something like a Cantor set is removed, the resulting thing is still a manifold, being an open subset of a manifold.

Comment: @user29751 In the question you talked about removing things that were manifolds. That's all I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, removing any closed  set from a manifold (topological, smooth, complex, symplectic...) leaves a manifold of the same kind, because the charts restrict to open subsets. One should note that the remaining manifold may be disconnected.

Removing a set which is not closed, generally, does not preserve the manifold structure, even if the removed set is itself a manifold. For example, remove an open line segment from a plane (example given by Chris Eagle).